# React - Next.js configuration with cssModules and url-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, css-modules

I need to configure **next.config.js** file in order to use in the same time two different loaders.
This is the first:

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

module.exports = withSass({
    cssModules: true,
    cssLoaderOptions: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
    }
})
```

And this is the second:

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
    webpack (config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 100000
                }
            }
        })
        return config
    }
}))
```

Individually they work great!
But I'm not able to combine them in a single rule so that both can work together.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: check this https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/241#issuecomment-411845052

Answer (score 6):

You should use next-compose-plugins. Here is a link below for additional reference.

[How can I combine multiple loaders (CSS, LESS, ttf, etc) in NextJS config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671281/how-can-i-combine-multiple-loaders-css-less-ttf-etc-in-nextjs-config-file)

**But the code below should solve your issue:**

**Install**

```
yarn add --dev @zeit/next-css
yarn add --dev @zeit/next-sass file-loader url-loader
```

**Update your next.config.js file**

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const sass = require("@zeit/next-sass")
const css = require("@zeit/next-css")

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: function (config) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 100000,
        name: '[name].[ext]'
      }
    }
  })
  return config
  }
}

module.exports = withPlugins([
  [css],
  [sass, {
     cssModules: true
   }]
], nextConfig);
```

**Note: You should now be able to import scss modules like this:**

```
import styles from 'your-file-name.module.scss'
```

**Note: Watch out for vendors libs that are not formatted properly in that case you should import as follows:**

```
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
```

Comment: This is giving **background-image: url([object Module])** output for me in the resulting css file. Any idea what might be causing it?